# Prolog - numbers to words

Tags: prolog

Im trying to write a code where if I run `english(X).` in Prolog I get a list of numbers 1-100 in linguistic form (one, two,....,twenty five,...,one hundred).
Is there a way to do this with a lexicon? I want to write a predicate for a pattern with how the "-teen" works. a predicate for the "-ty" and also a predicate for (twenty one, twenty two)? and when I say english(X). I should get a list of all the numbers. (one; two; three;....fifty one; .... one hundred. )

```
digit(0).
digit(1) :- 
    write(one).
digit(2) :- 
    write(two).
digit(3) :- 
    write(three).
digit(4) :- 
    write(four).
digit(5) :- 
    write(five).
digit(6) :- 
    write(six).
digit(7) :- 
    write(seven).
digit(8) :- 
    write(eight).
digit(9) :- 
    write(nine).





I have this so for and I am trying to write a predicate but having a hard time.
```

Comment: See: [Roman Numerals](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Roman_numerals/Encode#Prolog)

Comment: See: [Spelling of ordinal numbers](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Spelling_of_ordinal_numbers#Prolog)

Comment: See: [Number names](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Number_names#Prolog)

Answer (score 0):

The links provided by Guy Coder give an excellent general case version.
Here is a solution that respects your starter code, although you should think about how you can make it neater and more general (including by consulting the links!)

```
english(X) :-
  X<10, !,
  digit(X).

english(X) :-
  X<20, !,
  teen(X).

english(X) :-
  X<100, !,
  Units is X mod 10,
  Tens is X - Units,
  tens(Tens),
  digit(Units).

english(100) :-
  write('one hundred').

teen(10) :-
  write('ten'). % etc 10 to 19

tens(20) :-
  write('twenty'). % etc 20 to 90

digit(0). % etc. 1 to 9 (as original digits)
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with a lexicon? I want to write a predicate for a pattern with how the "-teen" works.  a predicate for the "-ty" and also a predicate for (twenty one, twenty two)? and when I say english(X). I should get a list of all the numbers. (one; two; three;....fifty one; .... one hundred. )

Comment: @shay For the lexicon, look at your 'digit' facts and compare with the 'tens' and 'teens' facts. It shouldn't be difficult to give them all the same name, so that it forms a lexicon.

Comment: @shay, for the predicate for twenty-one, twenty-two... It works, I suggest you try the code, to see what it's doing, read it, trace it, you'll see your way through.

Comment: @shay finally, about "teen", "ty". Basic 'facts' or rules with 'write' are better options IMO. You could write a rule that adds [t,e,e,n] to the unit word, but it would only work for 3 of the teens (16, 17, 19). Same with 'ty', only 60, 70, 90, work strictly to rule.